# nmake fails to compile TSF samples with VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, nmake, text-services-framework

I'm trying to build [**Text Services Framework Sample Codes**](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/tsf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1755) using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 RC 64bit. The instructions on these samples were based on VS 2003. Here's the part of that (wrote my problems in **bold**)

> 1. Open a command window.
> 2. Run vsvars32.bat. If you have Visual Studio .NET 2003 installed on your C: drive, the command is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat".
> 3. Run SetEnv.bat. If you have Visual Studio .NET installed on your C: drive, the command is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\SetEnv.bat" /RETAIL. (**I couldn't find the file on my system**)
> 4. Navigate to the sample directory.
> 5. Run nmake. (**Getting error here: win32.mak not found**)

What might be the possible solution?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2011 same issue is happening how to run dll file

Comment: For what it's worth, the TSF examples do compile under VS2010's command prompt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a command window.
2. Run vsvars32.bat. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat".
3. Copy win32.mak from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include to the sample directory.
4. Navigate to the sample directory and run nmake.

Answer (score -2):

Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt. This loads the required variables.

Comment: Uh No. (at least on my Win7 VS2012EE install). It seems that Win SDK8 is installed with VS2012EE and that Win SDK8 does not have a win32.mak. Using win32.mak from my previously installed Win Sdk 7 does seem to work.