# Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, build, nmake

[[MS.Docs]: Sample Makefile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sample-makefile) (for *VStudio **2022*** (*17*) at question creation time) contains the following (*Makefile.mak*):

```nmake
# Sample makefile

!include <win32.mak>

all: simple.exe challeng.exe

.c.obj:
  $(cc) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvars) $*.c

simple.exe: simple.obj
  $(link) $(ldebug) $(conflags) -out:simple.exe simple.obj $(conlibs) lsapi32.lib

challeng.exe: challeng.obj md4c.obj
  $(link) $(ldebug) $(conflags) -out:challeng.exe $** $(conlibs) lsapi32.lib
```

which doesn't work *OOTB*:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073159159]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> nmake /f Makefile.mak
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30146.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Makefile.mak(3) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found
> Stop.
> ```

Results on the web (especially [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)) are a lot scarcer than I expected:

- [[MS.MSDN.Social]: ntwin32.mak not found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4db6024e-cb2c-4992-9fb8-4aeefc194733/ntwin32mak-not-found?forum=vssetup) which states (proposes a fix):

  > The file is included with the v7.1 SDK. Once the v7.1 SDK is installed, you can add it to the 'include' environment variable at the command prompt by entering 'set include=%include%;%programfiles(x86)% \Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include' (without the quotes).
- [[MS.MSDN.Social]: How-to use ntwin32.mak on VisualStudio2015](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fe660bd-c3c2-442b-9e31-9493ae091d4b/howto-use-ntwin32mak-on-visualstudio2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

  > As far as I know, starting with the Windows 8 SDK, it contains MSBuild, so the makefiles were removed.
- [[Google.Groups]: Visual Studio 12.0 win32.mak not found](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/PeIoexPdleg)
- [[MathWorks]: Why do I receive a fatal error "Error U1052: File 'ntwin32.mak' not found" when I try to simulate my model in accelerator mode in Simulink 7.5 (R2010a)?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94469-why-do-i-receive-a-fatal-error-error-u1052-file-ntwin32-mak-not-found-when-i-try-to-simulate-my)
- [[WireShark.OSQA-Ask]: file ‘win32.mak’ not found Stop.](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/4725/file-win32mak-not-found-stop)
- [[BetaArchive]: Microsoft KB Archive/133249](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/133249) (waaay too old, not related to this)
- [[SO]: file 'ntwin32.mak' not found error while making files for live555 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71370961/4788546)
- [[SO]: nmake fails to compile TSF samples with VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11422308/4788546)
- [[SO]: VS2010 to VS2015 porting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35594858/4788546)

Comment: Hi ,glad to know your issue has been solveed! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT: Thanks, it was already solved even before I asked the question (as I specified in the 1st version). I just wanted to document it, so whoever might run into the issue again would quickly get past it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 files (***Win32.mak*** - and its wrapper *NtWin32.mak*) are part of ***Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4***. 
It's the *SDK* version pairing *VStudio 2010* (*10*) and *VStudio 2012* (*11*) according to (**unofficial**) [[Wikipedia]: Microsoft Windows SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK). For some reason their presence has been discontinued in newer *SDK* versions. One possible reason (as stated by one of the *URL*s in the question) is that *MS* is encouraging *MSBuild* usage.

There are 2 steps required in order to make things work.

#### 1. Get the files locally

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. **They might already be present**. If any of the 2 *VStudio* versions mentioned at the beginning is installed, then this *SDK* version was most likely automatically installed as well. Since both *VStudio* versions are *pc032* (*032bit*), then the *SDK* is expected to be *pc032* as well. As a consequence, files location is typically: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include***. 
   Note that version might also be ***v7.0A***, but I'll use the former one as it's newer (and the 2 files are identical in these 2 versions).

   **Note**: since I have **9 different *VStudio* versions installed** (*v2010* and *v2012* among them), I have these files as well
2. **Download and install the *SDK* manually**

   - [[MS]: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442) - contains 3 *ISO*s - for each supported platform (including retired *IA64*)
   - [[MS]: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) - online installer which (most likely) downloads and installs one of the items from the previous bullet

   **Note**: check [[MS.Developer]: Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) for *SDK* versions.

   Installation of the (old) version might be a bit problematic on *Win10+* versions. For example, in my case just after launching the (*pc064*) installer, I got:

   [image: Img0]

   Since I already had the files, didn't go through with the installer. But the topic is discussed on [[MS.MSDN.Social]: Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 10](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1de7c9b4-1feb-4c98-b426-f7f02cbafa99/windows-sdk-71-on-windows-10?forum=windowssdk).
3. **Get the files from [[GitHub]: CristiFati/MSSDKFiles - (v7.1A_w10) Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://github.com/CristiFati/MSSDKFiles/tree/v7.1A_w10). Since none of the 2 ways above is very user friendly (not to mention that installing requires *Administrator* privileges), I uploaded them in this repository, where they can be downloaded from (using browser, *Git*, ...)**.
   **Note**: Some of the files contain modifications (to accommodate (some) macro values corresponding to newer *Win* versions: *Win 8*, *Win 10*, ...).

#### 2. Add them to *NMake* system

At the end of previous section, the 2 files should exist somewhere locally. For simplicity's sake, I'll be using as a test file:

*Makefile.mak*:

```make
# Dummy Makefile

!include <win32.mak>

all:
    @echo Executing target: $@ ($(MAKEDIR))
```

For building on *Win* examples, might want to check:

- [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546)
- [[SO]: Linking to CRT (unresolved external symbol WinMainCRTStartup) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71872682/4788546)

I'll be working with *VStudio **2019*** (and reuse the same *Cmd* console):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073159159]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak
> Makefile.mak(3) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found
> Stop.
>
> [prompt]> echo %INCLUDE%
> c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

1. **Copy files in *VStudio*'s *Include* *dir*** (as instructed by some of the *URL*s in the question)

   It doesn't work *OOTB*, as newer *VStudio* versions no longer have a generic "Include" *dir*, but they rather "delegate this task" to a subcomponent (and *dir*) called *Tools*

   - The advantage is that it only needs to be done once (per *VStudio* version and ***VStudio Tools* version**)
   - The disadvantage: **don't do it unless you really know what you're doing** (in which case **required** administrative privileges shouldn't be a problem). Messing up with system files repeatedly, might become a habit, and there's a great chance of overwriting (or deleting) something at one point, and therefore corrupting program installations (or even the *OS*)

   Example:

   > ```
   > [prompt]> :: @TODO - cfati: DON'T DO THIS! (Demo purposes only)
   > [prompt]> echo %VCToolsInstallDir%
   > c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\
   >
   > [prompt]> copy "e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\MSSDKFiles\src\Include\Win32.mak" "%VCToolsInstallDir%\include"
   >         1 file(s) copied.
   >
   > [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak
   > Executing target: all (e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073159159)
   >
   > [prompt]> :: Cleanup
   > [prompt]> del /f "%VCToolsInstallDir%\include\Win32.mak"
   >
   > [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak
   > Makefile.mak(3) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found
   > Stop.
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > ```
2. **Add files location (*dir*) to *%INCLUDE%* *env var*** (the other way around)

   ```bat
   if defined INCLUDE (set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;${Win32Mak_Directory}) else (set INCLUDE=${Win32Mak_Directory})
   ```

   ***${Win32Mak_Directory}* is a placeholder for the actual path**.

   Safe, it can't do any damage (at least not a permanent one, worst thing that could happen is messing up the environment in the current *Cmd* console, starting another would fix it). The problem is that it would have to be done every time building is required (after calling *VCVarsAll*), which (if happens often) can become annoying. To get rid of the "monkey work", change the (current user's) *env var*s (**once**) from either:

   - ***GUI*** (*Control Panel -> System and Security - >Advanced system settings* (*sysdm.cpl*) -> *System Properties -> Environment Variables -> New*)

     [image: Img1]

     If the variable is already defined, append *${Win32Mak_Directory}* to the existing value, separated by a *SemiColon* (***;***)
   - ***CmdLine*** ([[MS.Docs]: setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx))

     ```bat
     if defined INCLUDE (setx INCLUDE %INCLUDE%;${Win32Mak_Directory}) else (setx INCLUDE ${Win32Mak_Directory})
     if defined INCLUDE (set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;${Win32Mak_Directory}) else (set INCLUDE=${Win32Mak_Directory})
     ```

     **Note**: The `if defined` part (which seems odd - and a bit too complex) **is required to work in *Cmd*** (*Win 10* - check behavior below):

     > ```bat
     > [prompt]> set _UNSET=
     >
     > [prompt]> echo %_UNSET% ??? WTH ???
     > %_UNSET% ??? WTH ???
     > ```

     When placed in a *.bat* file, everything is normal (only the contents in the 1<sup>st</sup> parentheses is enough)

   Of course, there's the option of doing it directly from the registry, but I'm not going to insist on it.

   Example:

   > ```bat
   > [prompt]> set _INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%
   >
   > [prompt]> set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\MSSDKFiles\src\Include
   >
   > [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak
   > Executing target: all (e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073159159)
   >
   > [prompt]> :: Cleanup
   > [prompt]> set INCLUDE=%_INCLUDE%
   >
   > [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak
   > Makefile.mak(3) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found
   > Stop.
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > ```
3. **Create a wrapper over *VCVarsAll*** and call that one instead

   The wrapper would:

   - Call *VCVarsAll*
   - Adjust the *%INCLUDE%* *env var* (check previous item (*#2.*))

   (in **any** order), but I'm not going to go into more details

---

#### Summary

The simplest step sequence (only required once) to get things going:

1. Get files from [[GitHub]: CristiFati/MSSDKFiles - (v7.1A_w10) Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://github.com/CristiFati/MSSDKFiles/tree/v7.1A_w10) (tag *v7.1A_original* contains the files got from *MS*)

   1. The (green) button (combo-box) *Code -> Download ZIP*
   2. Unpack the downloaded archive contents in a folder. Let's refer to it by ***${MS71SDK}*** (**whenever seen in a command, replace it with the actual path**). The files will be located in *${MS71SDK}\Include*
2. Add their location to *%INCLUDE%* *env var* (from *Cmd*)

   ```bat
   set MS71SDKINC=${MS71SDK}\Include
   if defined INCLUDE (setx INCLUDE %INCLUDE%;%MS71SDKINC%) else (setx INCLUDE %MS71SDKINC%)
   if defined INCLUDE (set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%MS71SDKINC%) else (set INCLUDE=%MS71SDKINC%)
   ```
3. Build normally. *NMake* will pick the changes up

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the required file WIN32.MAK does not exist in the Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK).

To resolve this issue, You would need to include it from Windows SDK7.0 or 7.1 SDKs.The file should be located in the SDK's "Include" folder (for example, under **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7\Include**). You could download it on this [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8442).

If WIN32.MAK already exists in your computer, you can refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4db6024e-cb2c-4992-9fb8-4aeefc194733/ntwin32mak-not-found?forum=vssetup).